# Insufficient memory nfs most wanted

Tags: insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-ace-plus

I have samsung galaxy ace plus s7500 with 1.8 GB available internal storage and 8GB memory card. I want to run NFS most wanted on it that take around 2GB of space. Could you please tell me a way to run it on my phone. Please help. 
Thank you.